# Angular: preloading images from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ukaCGifwNfhqJmTHDwGR?p=preview

**What I want to achieve:**
I want the image to load successfully before it shows the image so that the image doesn't show little by little.

On my plunkr, it looks fine enough but on my live site, it loads little by little.

For reference: http://ishq.org/ --The image loads completely before it fades in.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

<div ng-controller="projectCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="x in vegetables">
      <button type="button" class="btn two btn-default" ng-click="open(x)">{{x.name}}</button>


</div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);



// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

app.controller("projectCtrl", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "$uibModal", function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $uibModal) {
    $scope.vegetables = [
    {name:'Carrot', dev: '1', age:25, gender:'boy', image:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Stourhead_garden.jpg"},
    {name:'Apple', age:30, gender:'girl', image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Inside_the_Batad_rice_terraces.jpg"},
    {name:'Beef', dev: '1', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Cow', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Chicken', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Pork', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'No ', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Brocolibeef', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'BeefBeef', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'HorseBeef', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];

   $scope.open = function (_details) {
     console.log(_details)
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'PopupCtrl',
            windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
            scope: $scope,
            resolve : {
                     details : function() {
                        return  _details;
                    }
                }
        })
        .result.then(function() {

        }, function() {

        });
    };


}]);

app.controller("PopupCtrl", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "$uibModal", 'details' , function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $uibModal , details) {
  $scope.vegetabledetails = details;
  console.log($scope.vegetabledetails)

}]);
```

MODAL:

```
<style>
  imgs{
    height:300px;
  }
</style>

<div class="vegetable-name">
 Name: {{vegetabledetails.name}}
</div>
<div class="age">
 Age: {{vegetabledetails.age}}
 <img src={{vegetabledetails.image}} class="imgs">
</div>
```

Comment: _"Side Note: Why isn't my modal taking my image styles?"_ `imgs` is not a valid selector at `<style>` element?

Comment: What research have you done? Should be able to find numerous similar posts regarding preloading images

Comment: your question is not clear once u clik the popup the image is loading ryt wht u expect ?

Comment: @guest271314 Fixed

Comment: @gayathri Edited for clarity.  For more info, like this page, the images load successfuly then fade in.

Comment: refre this i created the directive  https://plnkr.co/edit/5jfs567YfIygdtTn3lUx?p=preview

Comment: Hey @gayathri, that worked perfectly, if you put up an answer, I'll vote it best answer.  I'm not sure why it works but it gives me something to look at and study.  THanks again.

Comment: can not cz thy duplicate this answer so if u ask question again in diff only can post answer . :(